# Restrict count operations in OperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, nsoperationqueue

I need to restrict count of operations in a concurrent operations queue. To achieve it I use `operationsCount` property, and `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`.

```
    func exec(_ block: @escaping ()-> Void) {
        self.queue.addOperation(block)
        if (self.queue.operationCount == self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount)
        {
            self.wait()
        }
    }

    func wait() {
        self.queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
    }
```

In iOS 13 `operationsCount` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1415115-operationcount).
I know that I can use `DispatchSemaphore` with max count concurrent operations as value:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 10)
<...>
    semaphore.wait(timeout: DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    async{
    work()
    semaphore.signal()
}
```

But in my tests `wait` and `signal` do not have enough performance. How I can get operations count in iOS 13?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxConcurrentOperationCount` and spare yourself all the headache of semaphores. Limiting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` you can add as much operations to the queue as you want, but only the number you've specified will be performed concurrently.

Take a look at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount.

Comment: It is not what I want. If I have very big array of items, and create operation for every item, I will use too many memory for all this operations (for example, if my Array contains 100000 elements). Oh, also, I've updated code with semaphore (there was error).

Comment: Semaphore locks code before async call, I should do it to avoid holding too many objects in a memory.

Comment: In that case you can create another queue which will hold `maxConcurrentOperationCount` objects and create operations from them. After all the operations are finished, you can refill the queue. You don't have to create a real queue, you can process `maxConcurrentOperationCount` objects in the error each time. Then jump to the next `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.